# use variable as full where clause in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, where-clause

I am trying to do this:

```
DECLARE @str varchar(max)
  SET @str='BEGIN        
              SELECT count(*) FROM eCareMembers
            END'        
  EXEC(@str)
SET @cnt2=cast(@str as bigint)
SELECT cast(@cnt2 as varchar(max)) as usercount, *.a from user a
```

but i'm getting error: `Error converting data type varchar to bigint.`

Comment: @str contains the query text and can't be cast to bigint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not at all clear on what you're tring to do, but if you want to execute some piece of dynamic SQL and capture some of the results into variables, you should use [`sp_executesql`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx):

```
declare @Cnt int;
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = N'select @c = COUNT(*) from sys.objects';
exec sp_executesql @sql,N'@c int output',@Cnt output

print @Cnt
```

(Which, for me, prints 83).

Answer (score 0):

I understand. Try this:

`SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM eCareMembers) as usercount, *.a from user a`

Comment: what i want is that to store the count of a table but using set @str='begin end'. not using set @str=select count(*). and then use that @str to display count in other select statement

Comment: @user3410589 - it's not at all clear to me why this is being done as dynamic SQL, nor what you *think* `BEGIN`/`END` are doing for you. Could you edit your question and try to explain a bit more (also, your question title mentions a `WHERE` clause but there's no sign of one in the body, so that also points to some needed edits too)